# Show spinner only for long time requests with Angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, spinner, interceptor

I created an interceptor to show a spinner when an HTTP request is made:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinner.show();

    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => this.spinner.hide()));
  }

}
```

I'm using [ngx-spinner](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner) for that purpose.

I want to show the spinner only for HTTP requests that take more than 1 second, for example. I've been trying to use [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) but I'm not sure how to use it or if it's suitable for what I want.

Is there any way to do this using the interceptor?

UPDATE: 
I came to the solution after opening the question, it's very similar to @joyBlanks answer, this is what I did:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let finished = false;

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!finished) {
      this.spinner.show();
    }
  }, 1000);

  return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => {
    finished = true;
    this.spinner.hide();
  }));
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.spinner.show(), 1000)` does this work?

Comment: How will you know at the start whether a request is going to take more than a second?

Comment: if the req is finalized cancel the timeout and call hide explicitly, so if your request takes less than 1s it will never execute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a timer to show spinner after 1 sec.

If the request is completed < 1s you will never see it else it will be hidden if it is shown.

```
timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if(this.timer){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.spinner.show(), 1000);

  return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => {
    this.spinner.hide();
    if(this.timer){
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: I came to the same solution after opening the question, that is precisely what I have done. Thank you

Comment: cancelTimeout isn't recognized. Use clearTimeout instead.

Comment: lol my bad. didn't recognize this mistake. thanks. updated answer

Comment: When I use this solution, I get "Type Timeout is not assignable to type number".

Comment: @Dawid use `NodeJS.Timeout`

Answer (score 0):

As @jonsharpe said, you can't know which request gonna take more than 1 second(may depend on user connection speed) unless you have some requests in which you make big task like reading big files, making long cpu tasks etc...

If you want to show a spinner after 1 second pending request, go ahead with @joyBlanks's answer otherwise you will have to determine requests that actually take more than 1 second et handle a specific spinner for them